# Heucheln so, als ob vs tun, als ob

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage, verb-choice

> Er heuchelt so, als ob er alles wüsste.
>
> Er tut so, als ob er alles wüsste.

Kann man sie austauschbar verwenden? Wenn ja, werden sie einen großen Unterschied haben?

Comment: Der erste Satz klingt eher "fabriziert", weil *heucheln* in Zusammenhang mit *als ob* ziemlich ungewöhnlich bzw. mir sehr "heavy" erscheint. Denn es wird quasi die Bedeutung "verdoppelt". Aber *heucheln* und *so tun als ob* wären gleichwertig und ich würde spontan sagen austauschbar!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Heucheln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heucheln)** ist das *Vorspielen einer Emotion* und wird oft zusammen mit einem Substantiv benutzt. Es ist grundsätzlich negativ besetzt, es betont die Unaufrichtigkeit der Handlung oder des Handelnden.

> Er heuchelte Mitgefühl.

**So tun, als ob** ist zunächst neutral, man kann aus verschiedenen Gründen eine Handlung nur scheinbar durchführen. Es hängt vom Kontext ab, ob *so tun, als ob* negativ oder positiv verstanden wird.

> Er tat so, als hätte er nichts gehört.
>   (Weil sein Gegenüber laute Blähungen hatte, und er so eine peinliche Situation vermied.
>   oder
>   Weil er den Obdachlosen nicht grüßen wollte.
>   -> Kontext!)

So tun, als ob ist auch typisch für Spiele: Im Sandkasten *tut mein Kind, als ob es einen Kuchen gemacht hat und ich tue so, also ob ich ihn essen würde*.

Man könnte *heucheln* als Sonderfall von *so tun, als ob* sehen. Direkt austauschbar sind die Begriffe nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Nein, die beiden Begriffe sind nicht austauschbar verwendbar. Der erste Satz ist so nicht üblich - insbesondere "heucheln" in Zusammenhang mit "so", also "So heucheln als ob", während der zweite Satz problemlos verständlich ist.

Answer (score 0):

Das Verb »heucheln« hat zwei Bedeutungen:

**(1)** nicht seine wirklichen Gedanken äußern; etwas anderes sagen, als man denkt; sich anders geben, als man ist; sich verstellen

Beispiel:

> Du heuchelst doch nur, wenn du ihm Komplimente machst!

In diese Abteilung gehören auch diejenigen [Politiker, Geistliche, Wirtschaftsvertreter], die Wein trinken, aber Wasser predigen.

Verwandte Ausdrücke sind *Scheinheiligkeit*, *Maskerade* bzw. *Charaktermaske*, *unter falscher Flagge segeln*.

---

**(2)** nicht vorhandene Gefühle, Gemütszustände oder Eigenschaften als vorhanden erscheinen lassen, sie vortäuschen, vorgeben

Beispiel:

> Es geht ihm nur ums Geld, aber er heuchelt Interesse, um die Stelle zu
>   bekommen.

In diesem Sinne ist ein Heuchler auch der, der eine Verletzung vortäuscht, um Mitleid zu erregen (Simulant). Etwa, indem er eine Blutkapsel zerbeißt.

Ebenfalls in diese Abteilung gehören die *Krokodilstränen*, *Schmeichler* und die *Katzenfreundlichkeit*.

---

Deine Frage betrifft Fall **(2)** (Wissen heucheln = so tun, als ob man etwas wüsste), wobei – wie schon @Philipp Flenker sagte – nur der zweite Satz gebräuchlich ist (»Er tut so, als ob er alles wüsste.«).

Diesen Satz könnte man auch so formulieren:

> Er tut, als ob er alles wüsste.
>
> Er tut, als wüsste er alles.

Comment: Wenn Du schon von Duden kopierst, bitte wenigstens die Quelle angeben oder verlinken.

Comment: @Stephie: Heuchelt er Wissen? :)